# How flex handle ambiguous patterns

Tags: flex-lexer, lex

I want to use flex to handle patterns. In this case, both constant and function name are alphabetical strings that begin with an uppercase letter.
For example, in
`Mother(Liz, Bob)`, how can I differentiate `Mother` and `Liz`?
I want `(` to be a single token, so I can not regard `Mother(` as a pattern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally, it would be unnecessary to generate different token types for different kinds of identifier. The parser shouldn't need that distinction if the different uses can be distinguished syntactically. (If you need semantic information to differentiate, and a sentence could be ambiguous without that information, then you might need semantic feedback but that does not appear to be the case here.)

If you don't have a parser, you would need to do some syntactic analysis. Say, for example, that function names are *always* followed by a `(` -- which means that your language doesn't allow higher order functions. Then you could write a wrapper around `yylex` which reads one token in advance and emits a `FUNCTION_NAME` or `CONSTANT_NAME`, depending on the following token.